# Fonts Not Loading in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I can not read the copy in Google Chrome - the fonts are not loading
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a language other than English? What are you expecting? I see normal latin characters, just not legible English words. Please make your question more clear.

Comment: The issue seems to be a corrupted font for the font used for the Google Chrome UI. Basically, every alphabet is represented by a wrong character, *a* is shown as **`**; *b* as **a**; *c* as **b**; and everything else is moved by one alphabet before what it really is.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you had installed a corrupted version of the font that the Chrome UI is using.

The effect is that every letter is substituted by one letter before it (*a* is shown as `, *b* as a, *c* as b, and so on). So that:
`Take the Privacy Guide`
Becomes:
`` S`jd sgd Oqhu`bx Fthcd ``

What you need to do is reinstall the correct font instead of the corrupted one you installed (didn't you by chance installed a bunch of fonts before this happened?) I think that the font used for this is the font ***Roboto***.

1. Go to the Google Fonts page for the **Roboto** font: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto
2. Click **Download family** on the upper-right side of the page
3. Extract the downloaded **Roboto.zip** file
4. Select all the (12) font files in there and right-click, select **Install** from the right-click menu
5. ***Important:*** If prompted by Windows, *The 'Roboto' font is already installed. Do you want to replace it?* Make sure to click **Yes** on all.